# Novell Groupwise in Evolution

Tags: evolution

I want to use my GroupWise Account into Evolution, but afaik, the evolution-groupwise Plugin is discontinued. Is there any possibility to integrate it to Evolution?

Edit:
I'm using Archlinux + Evolution 3.16.4

Comment: Which version of evolution are you using, on what OS?

Comment: Archlinux + Evolution 3.16.4

Comment: The version from https://git.gnome.org/browse/evolution-groupwise does seem to be dead, but [this version](https://github.com/GNOME/evolution-groupwise) is still available (last update for 3.5.2 though..) - does that work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I have an compiling issue: Package requirements (libedataserverui-3.0 >= 3.5.3) were not met. But I'll try to work on that. Thank you

Comment: Any update on this as I am trying to do same ?